# Programmatically remove call waiting beep on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, ios6

Is it possible on an iPhone to programmatically remove the call waiting beep that happens if the iPhone is already on a call with another party and a third party calls the iPhone?

This would be for iOS 6 and iOS 7.

Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't. Your app doesn't have the ability to modify phone calls in progress, as phone calls are outside of the app's [sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672).

Comment: My application runs as a daemon on a jailbroken device meaning that it runs outside of the sandbox.  Is it still not possible to eliminate the call waiting beep in this instance?

Many thanks.